# Exchange Not Delivering Email

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I'm having an issue where my Exchange Edge Transport server receives mail (found in logs) and then it vanishes, never ending up in the users mailbox, I have a edge subscription setup between it and the main Exchange server, how can I go about tracing the message to figure out what is broken? I also have found records of the message in the logs on the main Exchange server.
Thanks a ton for any help
Edit:
If I change port 25 on my main router to point to the main exchange server as opposed to the Edge Transport, email comes through fine form external domains and delivered in the correct mailbox

Comment: 'found records of the message in the logs on the main Exchange server' - which one is 'main'?

Comment: I have two servers, one is just an Edge transport (running in Hyper-V) and one that is everything else(including hub transport). I just received a bounced email from the exchange server saying that the message is delayed "Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.7
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;400 4.4.7 Message delayed
Will-Retry-Until: Mon, 18 Oct 2010 01:00:45 -0300"

Comment: Also leading up to this I had a working edge transport, then we had a power outage and the battery backup never triggered a shutdown of the two servers, causing the database needing to be repaired "eseutil /p". The edge transport server however didn't survive as the virtual hard drive got corrupted so I rebuilt it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

"found records of the message in the logs on the main Exchange server"

"If I change port 25 on my main router to point to the main exchange server as opposed to the Edge Transport, email comes through fine form external domains and delivered in the correct mailbox"

Turn up the logging on the edge server and focus on the SMTP transaction between the two Exchange servers.